# How to solve unresolved reference issue in PyCharm?

Tags: python

I'm trying to use cpickle and urlretreive in my program in PyCharm:

```
from six.moves.urllib.request import urlretrieve
from six.moves import cPickle as pickle
```

However I keep getting the error "unresolved reference cpickle"

I have tried adding the six module in project interpreters in Pycharm but no luck.

I have Anaconda2 installed.

Please help thanks.

Comment: `cpickle` -> `cPickle`?

Comment: yes, how do i import it?

Comment: You did by doing `from six.moves import cPickle as pickle`. You can refer the module with `pickle`.

Comment: but Pycharm is underlining cPickle as red and gives a "unresolved reference 'cPickle'" error, how do i add the cpickle module class path in PyCharm?

Comment: not `cpickle`, but `pickle` because you imported it `as` `pickle`

Comment: yes, but how do i add the classpath to it?

Comment: I have the same issue. Errors are flagged by the IDE for "urlretrieve" in the first line and "pickle" in the second line. These 2 lines can be seen in Google's deep learning tutorial: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/udacity/1_notmnist.ipynb